# EntityFramework multiple Group by query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I want to print the names of the technology with the highest turnover on a daily basis. I have the order and order Items tables. I want to inner join these two tables and use the 'startdate' value from the Order table and 'Quantity' and 'finalPrice' in the orderitems table.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MostGiroOfTechnologies(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    using (TridiContext context = new TridiContext())
    {
        var technologies = (from oi in context.OrderItems
            join or in context.Orders on oi.OrderId equals or.Id
            where (or.Status == 5 || or.Status == 7)
            && startDate < or.CompletedDate
            && or.CompletedDate < endDate
            group or by new { or.CompletedDate.Date ,oi.Technology} into g
            select new 
            {
                startDate = g.Key.Date,
                technology = g.Key.Technology
                //price = ?
            }
        ).OrderBy(o => o.startDate).ToList();
        return Json(new { technologies });
    }
}
```

When I group by as above, I get the output I want, but the prices are null. When I add the price to the group by, the output is more than I want because it is also grouped by the prices this time.

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompletedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderEta { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public long? FinalPrice { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int SourceOfferId { get; set; }
}
public class OrderItems
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Technology { get; set; }
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public long? FinalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How should `price` be calculated? Try to use `g.Sum(...)`.

Comment: You are  grouping `OrderItems` by (..) so inside the group there is a collection of them. For sure the pricess differ and you have to decide which value is correct. Why the Order has a Price?

Comment: @GertArnold Should I include price in group by?Does it make sense to do this using group by or is there a different and nicer way?

Comment: @benuto When I include price in group by, orders with the same technology come as different rows because it is also grouped by prices. What I want to do. I will look at the orders for each day, I need to group the technologies of the ordered products and get the technology that gets the most deviations.

Comment: @GertArnold ' g.Sum(p=>p.FinalPrice) ' worked thanks so much friend.

Comment: Great! Please add this as an answer to your question to finish it off.

Answer (score 1):

this code work for me .

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult MostGiroOfTechnologies(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (TridiContext context = new TridiContext())
        {
            var technologies = (from oi in context.OrderItems
                join or in context.Orders on oi.OrderId equals or.Id
                where (or.Status == 5 || or.Status == 7)
                && startDate < or.CompletedDate
                && or.CompletedDate < endDate
                group or by new { or.CompletedDate.Date ,oi.Technology} into g
                select new 
                {
                    startDate = g.Key.Date,
                    technology = g.Key.Technology
                    price = g.Sum(p=>p.FinalPrice)  //this line
                }
            ).OrderBy(o => o.startDate).ToList();
            return Json(new { technologies });
        }
    }
```